# Problema con trigger BEFORE DELETE

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, trigger

Ya logré poner un trigger para disminuir la cantidad de productos que se venden, pero este código no corre cuando se devuelve un producto. Se borra una fila de la tabla.

Tengo dos tablas carrito de administración.

Este es mi código:

```
delimiter $$    
create trigger trgactustock  before delete on carrito    
for each row    
begin    
set @stock =(select Piezas From administracion where new.Id=Id);    
update administracion    
set Piezas= @stock +old.Cantidad where new.Id=Id;    
end;    
$$    
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Por favor, modifica la pregunta adjuntando tu dataset para hacer pruebas (phpMyAdmin, Exportar)

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que el error que obtienes es:

> There is no NEW row in on DELETE trigger

Por lo que únicamente tendría que cambiar los `new.` por `old.` quedándote el disparador así:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgactustock
  BEFORE DELETE ON carrito
  for each row    
  begin    
    set @stock =(select Piezas From administracion where old.Id=Id);    
    update administracion    
      set Piezas= @stock +old.Cantidad
      where old.Id=Id;    
end;
```

Lo he comprobado con el dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE administracion(
  Id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  Piezas int
  );
CREATE TABLE carrito(
  id_carrito int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  Id int,
  Cantidad int,
  FOREIGN KEY(Id) REFERENCES administracion(Id)     
  );

INSERT INTO administracion (Piezas) VALUES
  (7),(8),(9),(10);
INSERT INTO carrito (Id, Cantidad) VALUES
  (1,5),(2,6),(3,7);
```

Y, tras un:

```
DELETE FROM carrito WHERE Id=1;
```

Obtengo:

```
#   Id  Piezas
1   1   12
2   2   8
3   3   9
4   4   10
```

Answer (score 0):

En [la documentación de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html), se dice lo siguiente del trigger `DELETE`:

> In a DELETE trigger, only OLD.col_name can be used; there is no new row.

Y tiene sentido, pues, si vas a borrar un registro, entonces no hay uno nuevo, sino precisamente el viejo, el que borraste.

Sólo habría que cambiar el *keyword* `NEW` por el de `OLD`.